# Question on proving that $m(\bigcap_{I=1}^{\infty} E_i)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having difficulty on the following problem.

> Suppose that {$E_i : i \in \mathbb{N}$} is a sequence of measurable subsets in the interval $[0,1]$ satisfying $m(E_i)=1$ for each $E_i$. Prove that $m(\bigcap_{I=1}^{\infty} E_i)=1$.

I want to show that $m(E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \cdots \cap E_n \cap \cdots)=m([0,1])=l([0,1])=1$ but I am really struggling on how to continue. A **hint** that would point me in the right direction would be very helpful. Thank you for looking.

**Update:**

With the hint we have that since $m(E_i)=1 \rightarrow m(E_{i}^c)=0$ and by additivity $m(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i}^c)=0$. Also, $m(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i)=1-m((\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i)^c)=1-m(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{I}^c)=1-0=1$. $\Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $m(E_i^c)=0$, so $m\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i^c\big)=0$ by countable subadditivity.

Comment: I am still struggling on how to apply your hint in my problem. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: $m(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i)=1-m((\cap_{i=1}^\infty E_i)^c)=1-m(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i^c)$ by DeMorgan's laws, so to show that $m(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i)=1$ it is enough to show that $m(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i^c)=0$.

Comment: Your example looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. Just to check my understanding (with a small example). Let $A=[0,1], B=[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$, then $B^{c}=[0,\frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{3}{4},1]$. Hence, $m(B)=\frac{1}{4}=1-m(B^{c})=1-\frac{3}{4}$.